# Minimal Sample Size needed to have at least one element when there are 3 possible outcomes?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, sample-size

This is my first question here, I am really glad this community already answered so many from other users that have greatly helped me.

So here is my problem,

I have a pretty "large" sample (N>200) of trend predictions for which I have the 3 following outcomes
N = Neutral (nothing happened)
G = Good predictions
B = Bad predictions

from my "large" sample, I know the respective probabilities P(N), P(G), P(B).

What is the minimal sample size (of predictions), n,  that I need in order to have at least one Good prediction in the sample with a confidence of 95% or 99%. A generic formula would be best I guess

Sorry if this is not really formal and thank you very much for any input.